# React Native Expo giving; Application tried to present modally a view controller that is already being presented

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, expo-router

Im running into an issue i cant seem to fix ... Im using Expo Router and in my layout file in checking if the user is authenticated, if they are, send them to the (app) which is a tabs layout. If they are not authenticated, then return the welcome page.

After I log in and it goes to show the first page of the tabs, it crashes. But if i load the app back up, as it already has a token it loads the tabs fine, there seems to be an issue with the redirect which i cant seem to figure out.

I did a expo prebuild and ran it in XCode to see if I could see any errors, and the following showed up;

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally a view controller <RCTModalHostViewController: 0x11c4632f0> that is already being presented by <UIViewController: 0x107b0b7a0>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80049928d __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff800063894 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKitCore                           0x00007ff8051be215 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 5813
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00007ff8051bed86 __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 70
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007ff80622eac4 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 84
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007ff8051becdb __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 211
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007ff8051bf016 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 637
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007ff8051bebc8 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 165
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007ff8051bf0ca -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 153
    9   RentSafe                            0x00000001031cf284 __76-[RCTModalHostViewManager presentModalHostView:withViewController:animated:]_block_invoke.42 + 212
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106f77747 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106f789f7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106f88856 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1362
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106f882f6 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 31
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003f5850 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003f018b __CFRunLoopRun + 2463
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003ef409 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x00007ff80fcdd187 GSEventRunModal + 137
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805b703a2 -[UIApplication _run] + 972
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805b74e10 UIApplicationMain + 123
    20  RentSafe                            0x0000000102d586d0 main + 96
    21  dyld                                0x00000001063023ee start_sim + 10
    22  ???                                 0x0000000111cb13a6 0x0 + 4593488806
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This seems to be the cause;

```
Application tried to present modally a view controller <RCTModalHostViewController: 0x11c4632f0> that is already being presented by <UIViewController: 0x107b0b7a0>.'
```

I ahve no idea what this means or how to even go about fixing it. Im hopinf someone could shed some light on it. The code in my `_layout.tsx` file where the redirect is happening is as follows;

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Stack, useRouter, useSegments } from 'expo-router'
import { AuthProvider, useAuth } from '../context/AuthContext'
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font'
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen'
import { QueryClientProvider, QueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query'

const queryClient = new QueryClient()

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()

const InitialLayout = () => {
    const { authState, initialized } = useAuth()
    const segments = useSegments()
    const router = useRouter()

    const [fontsLoaded, fontError] = useFonts({
        'rob-thin': require('../assets/fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf'),
        'rob-light': require('../assets/fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf'),
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadFonts = async () => {
            if (fontsLoaded) {
                await SplashScreen.hideAsync()
            }
        }
        loadFonts()

        if (! initialized || ! fontsLoaded) return

        const inAuthGroup = segments[0] === '(app)'

        if (authState?.authenticated && !inAuthGroup) {
            router.replace('/(app)')
        } else if (!authState?.authenticated) {
            router.replace('/welcome')
        }
    }, [initialized, authState, fontsLoaded])

    if (! fontsLoaded) {
        return null
    }

    return (
        <>
            {authState?.authenticated ? (
                <Stack>
                    <Stack.Screen name="(app)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                </Stack>
            ) : (
                <Stack>
                    <Stack.Screen name="welcome" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="login" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="register" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                </Stack>
            )}
        </>
    )
}

const RootLayout = () => {
    return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <AuthProvider>
                <InitialLayout />
            </AuthProvider>
        </QueryClientProvider>
    )
}

export default RootLayout
```

If anyone has any insight or has seen this before it would be greatly appreciated. I've spent days trying to find a solution.

Note; My `AuthContext` is as follows;

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'

interface AuthProps {
    authState?: { token: string | null; authenticated: boolean | null }
    onRegister?: (name: string, email: string, password: string) => Promise<any>
    onLogin?: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<any>
    onLogout?: () => Promise<any>
}

const TOKEN_KEY = 'app-token'
export const API_URL = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URI
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthProps>({})

export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    const [authState, setAuthState] = useState<{
        token: string | null
        authenticated: boolean | null
    }>({
        token: null,
        authenticated: null,
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadToken = async () => {
            const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY)

            if (token) {
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`

                setAuthState({
                    token: token,
                    authenticated: true
                })
            }
        }

        loadToken()
    }, [])

    const register = async (name: string, email: string, password: string) => {
        try {
            return await axios.post(`${API_URL}/register`, { name, email, password, device_name: 'iPhone' })
        } catch (e) {
            return { error: true, msg: (e as any).response.data.message }
        }
    }

    const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
        try {
            const result = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/token`, { email, password, device_name: 'iPhone' })

            setAuthState({
                token: result.data.token,
                authenticated: true
            })

            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${result.data.token}`

            await SecureStore.setItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY, result.data.token)

            return result
        } catch (e) {
            return { error: true, msg: (e as any).response.data.message }
        }
    }

    const logout = async () => {
        await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY)

        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ''

        setAuthState({
            token: null,
            authenticated: null
        })
    }

    const value = {
        onRegister: register,
        onLogin: login,
        onLogout: logout,
        authState,
    }

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
}
```

and my login page is as follows;

```
import {
    Text,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Alert,
    View,
} from "react-native"
import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useAuth } from "@/context/AuthContext"
import Colors from "@/constants/Colors"
import { Stack, Link } from "expo-router"
import { useTogglePasswordVisibility } from "@/hooks/useTogglePasswordVisibility"
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons"
import { defaultStyles } from "@/constants/Styles"

const LoginPage = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null)
    const { onLogin } = useAuth()

    const { passwordVisibility, rightIcon, handlePasswordVisibility } = useTogglePasswordVisibility()

    const onSignInPress = async () => {
        setLoading(true)
        setErrorMessage(null)
    
        try {
            const result = await onLogin!(email, password)

            if (result.error) {
                setErrorMessage(result.msg || 'An unknown error occurred.')
            }
        } catch (e) {
            Alert.alert('Error', (e as any).message)
        } finally {
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }

    const loginButtonDisabled = !email || !password

    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
            style={styles.container}
        >
            <Stack.Screen
                options={{
                    headerShown: false,
                }}
            />
            <Spinner visible={loading} />
            <Text style={styles.header}>Welcome</Text>
            <Text style={styles.subheader}>Log in to continue</Text>
            <TextInput
                autoCapitalize="none"
                placeholder="john@doe.com"
                value={email}
                onChangeText={setEmail}
                style={styles.inputField}
                keyboardType="email-address"
            />
            <View style={styles.passwordInputContainer}>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="password"
                    value={password}
                    onChangeText={setPassword}
                    secureTextEntry={passwordVisibility}
                    style={defaultStyles.textInputWithIcon}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePasswordVisibility}>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name={rightIcon as any} size={20} color="#232323" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            { errorMessage && <Text style={styles.error}>{errorMessage}</Text> }

            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={onSignInPress}
                disabled={loginButtonDisabled}
                style={[styles.button, loginButtonDisabled && styles.disabledButton]}
            >
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: '#000', fontFamily: 'rob-light' }}>Sign in</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.remember}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'rob-light' }}>I don't know my password</Text>
                <Link href="/register" style={{ fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'rob-light' }}>
                    I don't have an account
                </Link>
            </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: '10%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
    header: {
        fontFamily: 'rob-light',
        fontSize: 28,
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    subheader: {
        fontFamily: 'rob-thin',
        fontSize: 16,
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginBottom: 40,
    },
    inputField: {
        marginVertical: 4,
        height: 50,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#cccccc',
        borderRadius: 12,
        padding: 10,
        fontFamily: 'rob-light',
        fontSize: 12,
    },
    passwordInputContainer: {
        marginVertical: 4,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        height: 50,
        width: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#cccccc',
        borderRadius: 12,
    },
    passwordInput: {
        padding: 10,
        width: '90%'    
    },
    button: {
        marginVertical: 15,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
        padding: 16,
        borderRadius: 12,
    },
    disabledButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#cccccc',
        opacity: 0.5
    },
    error: {
        marginTop: 10,
        color: '#CC3300',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 12,
    },
    remember: {
        paddingTop: 10,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: "space-between",
    }
})

export default LoginPage
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to navigate more than once at the same time to same page i think? You're rendering the app page if `authenticated`.

```
{authState?.authenticated ? (
  <Stack>
     <Stack.Screen name="(app)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
  </Stack>
 )
```

And you're redirecting if `authenticated` and if `inAuthGroup` false;

```
const inAuthGroup = segments[0] === '(app)'

if (authState?.authenticated && !inAuthGroup) {
    router.replace('/(app)')
```

What if your login page? Your `AuthContext`? Are you trying to navigate after login? Try to make it simple from one place without navigate multiple times.

When you put some values in dependency array of `useEffect` like this;

```
useEffect(() => {
    // .. Rest of your code .. //
}, [initialized, authState, fontsLoaded]) // <--- Here
```

This means that it will trigger the `useEffect` again whenever any value there changes. So, in your case you get `authState` from context and render the screens according to it. But `useEffect` being triggered and trying to navigate when `authState` changed. You can remove navigates from `useEffect` to see what happens.

And;
You can simply create a function isLoggedIn and just run once from useEffect like;

```
useEffect(() => {
        isLoggedIn();
}, [])
```

After your `isLoggedIn` function runs and change auth statements if the user has logged in, your render will change according to it. Give a shot.

Comment: That makes sense, would I just remove the code in the return statement? ... I have updated my question with both my AuthContext and my Login page

Comment: @BigJobbies I've updated the answer. Give a shot and keep us updated.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [facebook/react-native issue 37198](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37198), you might need to adjust your navigation logic to make sure any modal presentation or hiding is fully resolved *before* initiating a navigation action.
Using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) or hooking into modal lifecycle events like `OnModalHide` could help to prevent this race condition.

A simpler and more direct solution would be to check, before initiating a navigation action, if the app is already on the intended route. That prevents unnecessary navigation, which can be a source of race conditions.

Your `InitialLayout` component, using `setTimeout`, would be:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
// other imports

const InitialLayout = () => {
    const { authState, initialized } = useAuth();
    const segments = useSegments();
    const router = useRouter();
    // other states

    useEffect(() => {
        // font loading logic

        if (!initialized || !fontsLoaded) return;

        const currentSegment = segments[0];
        const isAuthenticated = authState?.authenticated;

        // Check if already on the correct route to prevent loops
        if (isAuthenticated && currentSegment !== '(app)') {
            router.replace('/(app)');
        } else if (!isAuthenticated && currentSegment !== 'welcome') {
            router.replace('/welcome');
        }
    }, [initialized, authState, fontsLoaded, segments]);

    // rest of your component
}
```

That now explicitly verifies whether the current segment matches the intended destination before initiating a navigation.

Comment: This didnt seem to work, it just looped the welcome and login screens

Comment: @BigJobbies OK. I have rewritten the answer to propose a simpler approach.